# Ngrok - Not loading wordpress posts after publish

Tags: wordpress, ngrok

I am using ngrok some problems occures :-

1. My wp main page not loading.
2. My stylesheets not loading.
3. Not able to access my wp dashboad

But solved all these three problems.

***So whats the problem now.***

I am not able to load the post after publishing the post it gives me.

> Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server. The
>   link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please
>   inform the author of that page about the error.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 404

I have checked the link also it is correct

Published url   ( Not works )

The link is http://myurl.ngrok.io/wp_blog/2018/08/24/test-post/

Draft url   ( Works )

The link is http://myurl.ngrok.io/wp_blog/?p=(postNumber)&preview=true

Comment: did you changed the permalink structure to other than default?

Comment: @charankumar changing permalink works thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the permalinks problem.

Change the permalinks from "default" to "post type"